# Check correct radio button based on db value

Tags: vue.js

I have radio buttons done via vue

```
<div class="flex-12-col radio-group" v-if="pet.product">
    <label>Choose a Reminder Message *</label>
    <div class="radio-group-radios">
        <div class="radio" v-for="application in pet.product.applications" :key="application.id">
            <input type="radio" :value="pet.applicationId" v-model="pet.applicationId" :name="`product-${pet.product.id}-application`" :id="`product-${pet.product.id}-application-${application.id}`">
                <label class="label" :for="`product-${pet.product.id}-application-${application.id}`">

                    <div class="quick-tooltip">
                        <div class="quick--tooltip-content align-center">
                            <!-- by default aligns to left. add class to above content wrapper 'align-right' 'align-center' to adjust positioning -->
                            <p>{{application.description}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {{application.name}}

                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Theres 2 radio buttons.

If the application id is 1, I want the first radio button checked. If id is 2, I want the second button checked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you bind each of your radio buttons to the same model, it should work.  Here's a simple example:

```
  <input type="radio" id="1" value="One" v-model="picked">
  <label for="one">One</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="2" value="Two" v-model="picked">
  <label for="two">Two</label>
  <br>
  <span>Picked: {{ picked }}</span>


var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        picked: '2'
    }
});
```

Here's a repl.it you can play with: https://repl.it/@jmbldwn/vueJS